# Java, Object Oriented Programming

Tags: java, oop

Can anybody help me with the followings please: 
- I have a Gomuku class that extend Model, and I need a copy constructor but instead of re-initializing everything, I would like to call Model constructor from Gomuku class:

```
//this is Model constructor   
     public Model ( Model other ) {
    this.w = other.w;
    this.h = other.h;
    this.blacksTurn = other.blacksTurn;
    this.gameStarted = other.gameStarted;
    this.gameOver = other.gameOver;
    this.blackWon = other.blackWon;
    this.whiteWon = other.whiteWon;


    if (other.w <= 0 || other.h <=0) return;
    this.board = new Piece[other.h][other.w];
    this.winningSequence = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int r=0; r<other.h; r++){
        for(int c=0; c<other.w; c++){
            this.board[r][c] = Piece.None;
        }
    }
}

//this is Gomuku 
    public Gomoku ( Gomoku other ){
    //I want to call Model constructor instead of initializing in here.
    //other.winningSequence = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Comment: I don't know about others, but I'm very confused as to just what it is you're trying to do and where you're stuck. If you don't get a decent answer soon, please consider adding more detail and code to your question, including **your own attempt** to solve the issue that you're stuck on complete with an explanation of what is wrong with this attempt.

Comment: are the classes related? Does `Gomoku extends Model`?

Comment: Also while you're at it, do consider improving your question title. It should be a brief yet very informative summation of your current problem, not vague and overly broad (which yours currently is). In my experience, the two most important keys to initially attracting the right experts to your question are your question title and your question tags. You will want those to be very high quality. You can edit your question by clicking this link: [edit]

Comment: luk2303, yes Gomuku extends Model

Comment: So in sum: **please show us your own attempt at creating this constructor**. Good luck!

Comment: Mr. Getting Better, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a copy constructor in Model. You need y use simply Model constructor, which is possible with Gooko object, because Gomoku extends Model. Please check [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).

```
 public Gomoku ( Gomoku other ){
   super(other); // this will initialize all Model properties
   // set other properties, that belong only to Gomoku 
 }
```

By invokin `super(object)` you are refering to Model constructor, that accepts Model as an argument. Because Gomoku  extends Model, you can use Gomoku object here.

In your Model class you have a problem with property order. 
Line containing

```
if (other.w <= 0 || other.h <=0) return;
```

Can break initializing of winningSequence list, so you can initalize it before the declared constructor.

```
class Model{
private List<?> winningSequence = new ArrazLis<>();

 public Model ( Model other ) {
  // your constructor
 }
}
```

or

```
  public Model ( Model other ) {
      this.winningSequence = new ArrayList<>(); // use this before if statement
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `super` :

```
public Gomoku ( Gomoku other ){
    super((Model) other); // Model constructor instead of initializing in here.
}
```

Subclass Constructors at [Interfaces and Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) has a sample to guide you over this as well.